# ADB device stuck in "connecting" state

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to connect my phone to Android Studio to follow up with some app development. I am currently struggling with connecting my phone to the computer properly, as ADB never seems to connect to the device.

When attempting to boot the app on the device, this is what Android Studio tells me in the run console

```
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device still connecting
Error while Installing APK
```

Which leads me to think that this is a problem with ADB. So when I run `adb devices` I get this log:

```
List of devices attached
5210a780f48b44c5        connecting
```

It stays in the "connecting" state no matter how long I wait. I accepted USB debugging and file transfer.

When in Android studio, the device is listed as [image]

I'm out of ideas as to how to fix this. I recently updated my phone (Samsung A5) to Android 8.0. This phone connects and debugs fine on my work computer. I tried updating Android Studio, rebooting my computer, installing Samsung drivers, rebooting my phone, revoking debug access, to no avail. I was able to work on this computer a while back but I don't know what changed.

How can I fix this problem so I can debug on my device?

[EDIT]
`adb version` shows this

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
Version 4797878
Installed as C:\Users\Frederic\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A friend told me to try to swap ports to a USB 2.0 instead of USB 3.0. After doing so it worked instantly as expected.

[EDIT]
It appears that this has more to do with the capabilities of the motherboard than the version of USB the port is. The opposite might be true for you, or just any other port.

Comment: Weird, I had the same problem when using a USB 2.0 port and it's fixed now after swapping to USB 3.0.

Comment: this was my problem too. and it only started occuring after updating to android 11. Very starnge but i tried everything and this was the only thing that worked..

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found that the issue was solved by switching off USB debugging on the device, then switching it on again.

Comment: Seems like the good old turn on and off again works for some users. In my case it was about the USB port not being supported

Comment: I also solved this problem by turning off and on Developer's Option again from Settings app.