# Failed to boot android virtual device (AVD) when data is stored on USB memory stick

Tags: android, android-studio, exfat-fuse

After successfully setting up a new virtual device with Android Virtual Device manager, booting fails and reports the following error:

> 10:28 Emulator: emulator: ERROR: A snapshot operation for 'Nexus_5X_API_28' is pending and timeout has expired. Exiting...
>
> 10:28 Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

This sounds similar to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055863/emulator-error-a-snapshot-operation-for-nexus-4-api-27-is-pending-and-timeou) by [Anjan Biswas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2555056/anjan-biswas), yet with a possibly different context:
- OS: OpenSuse Leap 42.3
- Android Studio 3.2.1: installed and run from exfatfs memory stick
- .android/avd/{my device} directory holds no "*.lock" file
- The user running Android Virtual Device manager is also the actual owner of .android/avd directory tree.

The message happens exclusively when emulator data is actually saved on the memory stick (either through a symbolic link or by setting ANDROID_SDK_HOME environnement variable).

Explicitely:
- When emulator data is saved on HDD in "/home/{user}/.android" everything works just fine.
- When emulator data is saved on memory stick in "{exfatfs mount point}/.android" error occurs.
- Tried with fat32 file system with same issue.

Looking for a fix to avoid saturate /home with large android virtual device cache.

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! I have had issues with Android & USB ports before, maybe simply swapping them would help like it did for my physical device? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51458051/2535257

Comment: This is not related to programming, id it?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, it seems to be the problem of exfat format.
I tried to mount an apfs disk and the problem disappeared.